# Dart main() startup sequence

Tags: dart

It seems that Dart applications execute their compiled main() function in a thread (isolate) long after the enclosing HTML page has loaded and other scripts on the page have completed.  This makes it impossible to inject functions into the document for use by other web components.

e.g. I have UI components that initialize themselves using jquery setup... I'd like to have these UI components delegate to a controller written in dart and this works just fine as long as I set them up in the right order.  I could go so far as to call back from dart into JS and run my UI setup but... this is just a bridge to far...  (I've already talked myself down from using web components, etc. and resigned myself to using Dart as one big controller of JS functions for now... but if I have to jump through hoops to get even that to work... sigh.)

1) Is there some way to get dart to initialize itself synchronously or to control the initialization process?

2) Is there at least some logical boundary where dart is initializing itself? Some event that I should be targeting for all mysetup after which I know it has run?

Note: this has nothing to do with where the script tag invoking dart is placed or whether it is set to sync or async... Dart seems to spawn an isolate and invoke main() at a later time intentionally.

UPDATE: 
It looks like document.ready does fire after main, although I'm not 100% sure it's consistent.

UPDATE 2:
It appears that the packages/browser/dart.js bootstrap loader is causing the delay.  I have found that I don't need this and I can simply import the compiled dart js files directly and they work as expected.  e.g. if my app is helloworld.dart I can just load  and it behaves as expected.  Perhaps this should have been obvious, but I had not seen anyone utilize the standalone compiled dart in this way before.

As a bonus I should note that you do not need pub to build these you can just link packages into the source dir and build your JS with dart2js -o outfile.  Again, perhaps obvious but without knowing what else the build or bootstrapper does you may not think to try this.

Comment: Can't you just call a single js function from `main` e.g. `dartReady`?

Comment: You can fire an event from your main yourself that you listen to in JS.

Comment: Yes, thanks, to both of the above and I did suggest that in my original post however I saw this as gross.  I believe I have it all working now by just skipping the bootstrapper and loading the js directly... it seems to execute synchronously then.